# Reset debug/verbose mode logging in bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, redirect, debug

I use a cronjob as root to check via lsof if some remote machines have established an ssh tunnel to the main server (root, otherwise lsof and netstat won't show the username and sshd pid).

Then for each connection I want to run deploy scripts that perform a bunch of tasks on those connection:

```
for script in "${deploy_scripts[@]}"
do
    set +e
    sudo -u $deploy_user -H ${script} $user $port $conpid 2>&1 > /tmp/deploy.log
    res=$?
    set -e
    if [ $res -ne 0 ]; then
        echo error executing in $script
        cat /tmp/deploy.log
    fi
done
```

and each deploy script essentially looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
set -e
user=$1
port=$2
pid=$3
do stuff
```

However the deploy.log is always empty and I want to know when stuff fails.
I tried with [exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173131/redirect-copy-of-stdout-to-log-file-from-within-bash-script-itself) and [BASH_XTRACEFD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811439/bash-set-x-logs-to-file), but I don't know how to reset this after each deploy script so it doesn't capture the root script.
The deploy scripts should be unaware of this logging.

Comment: use `&> /tmp/deploy.log` rather than `2>&1 > /tmp/deploy.log`, also try extending PATH in your cron script by setting `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/etc` after `#!/bin/bash`, also it's better to alway leave empty line after `#!/bin/bash` before any commands

Comment: apparently `&>` instead of `2>&1 >` solved it. However from what I understand this should be the same(?)
What would be the advantage of extending the path?

Comment: not exactly, you can read about it here: https://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-shell-script-idiom-redirect/ and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean